# Move files two directories up & delete directories afterwards, using wildcards

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, terminal.app

I have a folder structure like the below.

> 1/data/f4aa9d39291bc37a7cacedfab656a941/x1.jpg

The first slot and the random string in the third slot vary depending on the folder. (Let's say for this example, I have 30 folders at that top level, in an incrementing fashion.)

I need to move the JPGs up two levels, so it's using this folder structure and deletes that **data** folder in each directory as it goes along:

> 1/x1.jpg

I searched for any examples that could help, but I think because of the wildcard aspect I'm running into an issue. I had tried the below (note in the code I went one level up), but it didn't work.

```
find 1/*/data/*/. -name '*.jpg' -exec cp {} 1/* \;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Combining both elements would be ideal, but I'm alright with help just for the non-deletion portion as I probably can write up a separate deletion script if I needed to.

(I'm using macOS's Terminal, if that affects anything code-wise.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your directory structure is

```
1/data/f4aa9d39291bc37a7cacedfab656a941/x1.jpg
```

and only `data` is a fixed string, then wildcards in the find command would be

```
find */data/* -name '*.jpg'
```

Run that command and see if the output is what you expect.

Running a batch script or command to delete files or directories is always dangerous.

This command will only move the files to the parent directory two levels above.

```
find */data/* -name '*.txt' -exec bash -c 'file={};path=${file%/*};name=${file##*/};echo "mv -v $path/$name ${path%%/*}"' \;
```

Run that and see if the output appears ok to you. It will only print the command line without actually execute it.

To really run the command, erase the `echo` command and the double quotes

```
find */data/* -name '*.txt' -exec bash -c 'file={};path=${file%/*};name=${file##*/};mv -v $path/$name ${path%%/*}' \;
```

To delete empty directories, the command would be like this, a little more safe since `rmdir` only deletes empy directories.

```
find */data/* -name '*.txt' -exec bash -c 'file={};path=${file%/*};name=${file##*/};echo "mv -v $path/$name ${path%%/*} && rmdir -v $path && rmdir -v ${path%/*}"' \;
```

Comment: That command worked perfectly, thank you so much!

(At first it didn't run and I was confused until I saw the .txt --- just had to change it to .jpg and it worked without a hitch.)